# Using While and For Loops to Assign a New Variables in R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble understanding how to answer this question for an assignment since the parameters seem so vague. I've loaded a package called large_vector already and it consists of 2461837 numeric elements.

The questions are as follows:

"Use a while loop to assign a new variable, mean_while, the mean of large_vector. use print to display this value."

"Use a for loop to assign a new variable, mean_while, the mean of large_vector. use print to display this value."

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to compute the mean of the data in large_vector using both kinds of loops. I would rewrite instructions as following:

"Create a new variable named mean_while and assign to it the value of the mean of large_vector by using a while loop, then print it to screen by using the print function (included in r)"

"Create a new variable named mean_for and assign to it the value of the mean of large_vector by using a for loop, then print it to screen by using the print function (included in r)"

If you dont know what for or while loops are. They are control structures that can help you when you want to operate iteratively trough a vector. In your case, to get the mean of large_vector, you can use the loop to add up the elements in large_vector and divide the result by the length of large_vector, wich you can get it like this:

```
length(large_vector)
```

Heres a little example of a for loop wich you can use to get the sum of values in large_vector.

```
i = 1 # variable to cicle loop
suma = 0 # creating variable suma and initializing to 0
# little for loop to get sum of values in large_vector
for(i in 1:length(large_vector)){
     suma <- suma + large_vector[i] 
}
```

And you can print it like this

```
print(suma) # using print function to print suma
```

I hope this gives you a better understanding.